# how to give backend login acces to groups/roles other than administrator in fuelphp?

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I am using Ormauth as auth package and used it for login at backend. Now I want to give login access for group 'moderator' along with 'superadmmin' and 'administrator'. How I am to proceed ? I tried changing options in default fuelphp tables for 'user_roles', 'user_role_permissions' and so on but to no avail. I am new to this ? Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does login access mean? I am not really sure how the question is related to the description you gave. Is moderator a group or a role? BTW  super admin has access to everything, no need to manually add.

Answer (score 0):

i do this: 
create a base class for admin area, in function "before" of that base class use \Auth::has_access('area.permission') for check that current user has access to current controller or not,

create some permissions (in table users_permission) for your admin area, you can use any names for area and permissions here but i suggest use your application or module name as "area" and controller name as "permission",

if you wish to use "groups" so use "users_grouppermission" or if you wish to use "roles" then use "users_rolepermission" for inserting some recordes for allowing access to groups/roles,

at least assign users to that groups or roles (using user_roles and user_groups tables)